# Regular expression failing to validate xml against xsd

Tags: regex, validation

I'm trying to fix a bug in a xsd file that someone else has written years ago. The problem is that xml is not validating against the xsd.

The error message returns following:

> "The value '0:0|-?\d{0,3}.*[0-9]+:-?\d{0,3}.*[0-9]+' of the facet 'pattern' is not a valid regular expression."
>
> "WXS schema fileName.xsd failed to compile"

(I'm using xmllint to validate)

I'm not good with regular expressions, so can someone explain what this is doing?

```
0\:0|\-?\d{0,3}\.*[0-9]+\:\-?\d{0,3}\.*[0-9]+
```

If I remove the `'\'` (backslash ) before every column `':'` so it looks like this:

```
0:0|\-?\d{0,3}\.*[0-9]+:\-?\d{0,3}\.*[0-9]+
```

Then error disappears, schema compiles and the xml validates. But what are these changes and does the regex still keeps it's original intended functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both regexes are the same, backslash isn't required for colon character.

Here is a visual explanation:

[image]

Which is:

- 0:0

or

- 0/1 minus
- 0/1/2/3 digits
- 0/1 dot
- 1+ digit
- 1 colon
- 0/1 minus
- 0/1/2/3 digits
- 0/1 dot
- 1+ digit